Unused Balance Option Warnings in ACM Template
When I use \documentclass[sigconf,balance=false]{acmart},
it outputs the warning LaTeX: Unused global option(s): [balance=false].
However, if I remove the term "balance=false",
it outputs Package balance: You have called \balance in second column (balance).
How can I solve this problem?
Additional Information:

acmart.cls version 2024/05/27 v2.08
This warning appears after I upgraded MacTeX (TeX Live) from version 2022 to 2024.


In in single-column document the option should not be needed and \documentclass[sigconf]{acmart} would not result in the second warning. So I'm a little nit confused. Maybe you are also using either option twocolumn or command \twocolumn somewhere? It would always be useful to show a minimal working example to make a problem reproducible and avoid such confusion.

After some tests, I'm quite sure, this is an issue with package xkeyval, which is used by acmart to handle the key-value options. I've also tested with TeX Live 2022 and the same happened there. So it is not really a new issue. Even the example from page 19 of the current xkeyval manuals reports a unused option bool=true. Unfortunately I cannot find how to report bugs/issues with this package. So I would recommend to first report it to acmart. Maybe this would be the occasion to switch to LaTeX's native key-value options.

I have reported the issue here.

@cabohah Thank you very much for reporting the issue to acmart! I am indeed using the double-column format for my paper. I am not familiar with this, but I don't seem to have explicitly used a command like \twocolumn anywhere. It seems that the double-column format is implicitly used for sigconf after setting some acm variables (as the official example)? I have no idea about this.

Class acmart uses package xkeyval for the options and it seems, that if this package is used in a class, the option are always reported as unused. Even the example from page 19 of the xkeyval manual:
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
%myclass.cls
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\define@boolkey{myclass.cls}%
[cls]{bool}{}
\ProcessOptionsX
\LoadClass{article}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mypack.sty}
% mypack.sty
\define@boolkey{mypack.sty}%
[pkg]{bool}{}
\ProcessOptionsX
\end{filecontents}
% test.tex
\documentclass[bool=true]{myclass}
\usepackage{mypack}
\begin{document}\parindent0pt
\ifclsbool class boolean true \else class boolean false\fi\\
\ifpkgbool package boolean true \else package boolean false\fi
\end{document}

results in
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [bool=true].

As an alternative for setting the option at the optional argument of \documentclass, you can use \setkeys:
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\setkeys{acmart.cls}{balance=false}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\lipsum
\end{document}


But if you need to set balance=true this does not work, if the last page with balance=false would have more than one column, because it would result in the warning:
Package balance Warning: You have called \balance in second column
(balance)                Columns might not be balanced.

and the printing is the same as shown above. So in this case, you should add \balance yourself before the second column of the last page starts:
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\balance
\lipsum
\end{document}


But note, that other options can also result in an unused global options warning and not all of them can be replaced by a \setkeys command. For example:
\documentclass[sigconf,twocolumn]{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\balance
\lipsum
\end{document}

or
\documentclass[sigconf,twocolumn]{acmart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AtBeginDocument{\balance}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}

would also result in the warning:
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [twocolumn].

nevertheless the printed result is as expected.
You could again work-around this incorrect warning using:
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\twocolumn\balance}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}

resp. for unbalanced columns:
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setkeys{acmart.cls}{balance=false}
\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\twocolumn}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}

But depending on the options used, these workarounds become increasingly complex and ugly. So maybe the best would be to just ignore the unused global options warning, if the options are correctly used.
Beside the problem with xkeyval, IMHO line 177 in acmart.cls:
\DeclareOptionX{*}{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{amsart}}

should be changed into:
\DeclareOptionX*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{amsart}}

After this change, option twocolumn is not reported as unknown any longer.

This method indeed worked! Thank you very much for the detailed answer!
